# Closing Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

When I try to open Thunderbird I get message that it already running and must close it before getting my messages. Cannot close the supposedly running Thunderbird. What is going on? How to fix without Terminal.
I am a newbie.

Comment: Looks like a bug [LP: #1932328](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1932328). If so, it occurs only when you use Wayland. The immediate workaround is to logout/login again. If you choose an X session at the password screen, you won't be affected by this bug at all. Developers are currently working to fix it.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, this may relate to a bug, but there is no indication that this is related to a development version. @user535733 your comment deserves to be a full answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the System Monitor, find the thunderburd process, and kill it.
Alternatively, run `pkill thunderbird` in a terminal window.

To actually fix it, you'd need to analyse and debug the problem, possibly edit the source code, and recompile. It will take a lot of time, so you probably want to skip it for now.

Comment: Any idea when this bug, if that is what it is, will be fixed. I'll try using gmail while waiting.

Comment: Thunderbird not listed in System Monitor. Is that part of the bug? Is there anyway that I could speed up a solution.